# Problem in opening melview

Tags: software-installation, python

I am facing a problem to open melview, an image(MRI) viewer software.I have installed all necessary dependencies for tis software. It was working fine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I have upgraded it to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I am facing this problem. It seems like some configuration has to be done for python in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

After installing melview and its dependencies I was trying to open melview. But got the following error message.

```
**pc@RB:~$ whereis melview  
melview: /usr/bin/melview /usr/local/bin/melview/usr/share/man/man1/melview.1.gz   
pc@RB:~$ melview   
No such file: ''  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/local/bin/melview", line 9, in <module>   
    load_entry_point('melview==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'melview')()     
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/melview/melodic_traits.py", line 863, in main  
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/melview/melodic_traits.py", line 514, in __init__   
nibabel.py3k.FileNotFoundError: No such file: ''   
pc@RB:~$ python melview
python: can't open file 'melview': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  
pc@RB:~$ python2.7 melview  
python2.7: can't open file 'melview': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  
pc@RB:~$**
```

Answer (score 1):

This is accurate. The issue is the updated ni-babel 2.1

This solves the error:

> No such file: ''
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/melview", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('melview==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'melview')()
>     File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/melview/melodic_traits.py", line 863, in main
>     File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/melview/melodic_traits.py", line 514, in **init**
>   nibabel.py3k.FileNotFoundError: No such file: ''

In Xubuntu 14.04 with neurodebian:

to fix:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-nibabel=1.2.2-1

sudo apt-mark hold python-nibabel
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in CentOS6.7, melview worked on nibabel version 2.0.2, but it didn't work on nibabel version 2.1.0.
Try reinstall older version nibabel.
"pip install nibabel==2.0.2"